# My trigger is not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I wanto to create a trigger in MySQL but it displays an error message when I run the creation code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON trigger
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    update users
    SET username= 'krishna',
        password= 'abc';
END
```

Error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'trigger FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO users SET username= 'kr'
>   at line 2

This is the code the error points to:

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON trigger
                 ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Seems like we need a more verbose description to help…

Comment: *Not working* is not a problem. Can you please show what is your actual problem?

Comment: i am new to mysql store procedure, i have table trigger  and user

Comment: error is some thing like this: -- "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'trigger FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO users SET username= 'kr' at line 2"

Comment: when i run this code in mysql the following error occurs

Comment: Do you really have a table named `trigger`? I guess you actually want: `before update on employee`.

Comment: ya i have table trigger

Comment: @Nirdosh - You should edit the question when you need to provide further info. Code in comments in unreadable. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRIGGER is reserved word in MySQL, you should quote this name -

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON `trigger`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users SET username = 'krishna', password = 'abc';
END
```

As a workaround - rename table `trigger`.

Comment: Use `DROP TRIGGER trigger_name;` comamnd. Or also you can do it using free GUI tool - [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (express edition).

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for `insert` is:

```
insert into users(username, password)
    select 'krishna', 'abc';
```

Your syntax is close to an update:

```
update users
SET username= 'krishna',
    password= 'abc';
```

Comment: @Nirdosh  . . . The operation is on a different table, so you can use either update or delete.

Comment: can u write me a simple trigger so that i can follow it's syntax, because i can't execute a single trigger in mysql.